# Snow leopard upgrade problem

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, installation, upgrade, macbook-pro

I'm running a MacBook Pro 2GHz with silver keys. Yesterday, I upgraded the RAM to the maximum 2GB and everything seemed happy on Mac OS X 10.4.

Today, I upgraded to Mac OS X 10.6.  Because I have a CD stuck in the drive, I made an image of the installation DVD on a USB stick and installed the OS from there. The installation proceeded as normal and the machine booted happily into Mac OS X 10.6.

However, I soon noticed a problem which I don't know how to solve. Basically, there is nothing appearing on the right hand side of the menu bar, i.e., no Spotlight, date, battery, airport, etc. Every so often the Spotlight icon appears and then disappears again.

Some aspects of finder seem to be working OK, e.g., I can load applications, I've been able to get to disk utility. I can log in and log out. But then randomly finder will freeze and I can't even access force quit (although in all cases the mouse will still move around the screen).

I'm currently checking disk permissions and I'll verify the disk as well but if anyone has come across this problem and solved it could you please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

It turns out the problem was because I had an application called "iStat Menus" running. This program does not work on OSX 10.6 and was causing problems. It is designed to put information about your system eg cpu usage, memory, fan speed etc etc into the menu bar. Because it wouldn't work under 10.6 it was obviously causing some conflicts with the information that should have been there.
I simply uninstalled the application and everything was back to normal!

Comment: I suspect the problem is just that you do not have the latest version of "iStat Menus". Many applications needed to be updated in order to work correctly with Snow Leopard. Check for an updated version if you are still interested in using it.